# Outputting multiple SQL queries in chart.js

Tags: php, sql, chart.js

So i have a chart created in chart.js that should output the results of my sql queries in the chart however when running the code, each section of the chart displays "1" everytime. So if the sections in the chart should be 12,2,5,9,11 from the queries shown in the code, it just shows 1,1,1,1,1. any idea where i've went wrong?

```
  <script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ['Body Pump', 'Spin Class', 'Yoga', 'Body Tone', 'Legs, Bums & Tums'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Total Number of Bookings',
      data: [
      <?php

      $resultbodypump = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT COUNT(SessionType) FROM bookings WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."' AND SessionType = 'bodyPump'");

      $resultspinclass = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT COUNT(SessionType) FROM bookings WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."' AND SessionType = 'spinClass'");

      $resultyoga = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT COUNT(SessionType) FROM bookings WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."' AND SessionType = 'yoga'");

      $resultbodytone = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT COUNT(SessionType) FROM bookings WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."' AND SessionType = 'bodyTone'");

      $resultlegsbumstums = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT COUNT(SessionType) FROM bookings WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."' AND SessionType = 'legsBumsTums'");

      echo mysqli_num_rows($resultbodypump) . ",";
      echo mysqli_num_rows($resultspinclass) . ",";
      echo mysqli_num_rows($resultyoga) . ",";
      echo mysqli_num_rows($resultbodytone) . ",";
      echo mysqli_num_rows($resultlegsbumstums);

      ?>
      ],
```

Comment: So what actually gets sent to the browser? Look at Page Source

Comment: page source shows that the data being sent is  [1,1,1,1,1]. When i run the queries in phpmyadmin they return the correct results however.

Comment: You have to FETCH results fromm a`mysqli_query()` they dont automatically get returned

Comment: There will always be exactly ONE row returned from a `COUNT()` only query so you have to FETCH the result not just do a `mysqli_num_rows()` on the query result

Comment: And one of your queries returns more than just the `COUNT()`

Comment: so something like a while loop with $data = $result->fetch_assoc() in it then echo $data?

Comment: No, each query will return only one row, so no while loop required

Comment: This was a great help, got the problem sorted, will post the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ['Body Pump', 'Spin Class', 'Yoga', 'Body Tone', 'Legs, Bums & Tums'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Total Number of Bookings',
      data: [
      <?php

      $querybodypump = "SELECT COUNT(SessionType) FROM bookings WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."' AND SessionType = 'bodyPump'";
      $resultbodypump = mysqli_query($db,$querybodypump);
      $row1 = mysqli_fetch_row($resultbodypump);
      $count1 = $row1[0];
      $queryspinclass = "SELECT COUNT(SessionType) FROM bookings WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."' AND SessionType = 'spinClass'";
      $resultspinclass = mysqli_query($db,$queryspinclass);
      $row2 = mysqli_fetch_row($resultspinclass);
      $count2 = $row2[0];
      $queryyoga = "SELECT COUNT(SessionType) FROM bookings WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."' AND SessionType = 'yoga'";
      $resultyoga = mysqli_query($db,$queryyoga);
      $row3 = mysqli_fetch_row($resultyoga);
      $count3 = $row3[0];
      $querybodytone = "SELECT COUNT(SessionType) FROM bookings WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."' AND SessionType = 'bodyTone'";
      $resultbodytone = mysqli_query($db,$querybodytone);
      $row4 = mysqli_fetch_row($resultbodytone);
      $count4 = $row4[0];
      $querylegsbumstums = "SELECT COUNT(SessionType) FROM bookings WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."' AND SessionType = 'legsBumsTums'";
      $resultlegsbumstums = mysqli_query($db,$querylegsbumstums);
      $row5 = mysqli_fetch_row($resultlegsbumstums);
      $count5 = $row5[0];

      echo $count1. ",";
      echo $count2 . ",";
      echo $count3 . ",";
      echo $count4 . ",";
      echo $count5 ;

      ?>
      ],
```